# Can I use variables inside {} expansion without `eval`?

Tags: bash, wildcards, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

Can I use variables inside `{}` expansion without appealing to `eval`? If so, how?

This doesn't work:

```
$ touch 1.foo 1.bar
$ ls 1.{foo,bar}
1.bar  1.foo
$ extensions=foo,bar
$ ls 1.{$extensions}
ls: cannot access 1.{foo,bar}: No such file or directory
```

It works with `eval`:

```
$ eval ls 1.{$extensions}
1.bar  1.foo
```

Comment: variable expansion happens after word expansion, so {$...} will be a single word. 'tho {$foo,$bar} would work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brace expansion happens very early during [expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) (first thing, in fact), before variable expansion. To perform brace expansion on the result of a variable expansion, you need to use `eval`.

You can achieve the same effect without `eval` if you make `extensions` a wildcard pattern instead of a brace pattern. Set the `extglob` option to activate [ksh-like patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```
shopt -s extglob
extensions='@(foo|bar)'
ls 1.$extensions
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to expand variables inside braces **without eval**:

```
end=3
declare -a 'range=({'"1..$end"'})'
```

We now have a nice array of numbers:

```
for i in ${range[@]};do echo $i;done
1
2
3
```

Tested in bash 4.3.11 but should work in all modern versions.

Comment: just a piece of syntax I used: `read line; declare -a "l=($line)"; echo ${l[@]}` — I placed this to let a user input brace-expanded strings and view the result (in a kind of bash tutorial).

Comment: In effect, that's like `eval`, it's not less dangerous than `eval`. With  `end='$(reboot)'`, `reboot` is run just the same.

Answer (score 2):

Another technique you can use in bash and some other shells
is to use an array:

```
$ extensions=(foo bar)
$ ls "${extensions[@]/#/1.}"
```

This is the
`${parameter/pattern/string}`
(pattern substitution) form of parameter expansion. 
(Unfortunately, this is not POSIX-compliant either.) 
The `[@]` specifies that the substitution should be applied
to each element of the array,
and that the separation between the elements should be maintained. 
`#` in a *pattern* string acts like a `^` in a regular expression
(i.e., most `s/old/new/` substitutions);
it means that the substitution should occur
only at the beginning of the parameter values. 
So

```
$ ls "${extensions[@]/#/1.}"
```

is equivalent to

```
$ ls "${extensions[0]/#/1.}" "${extensions[1]/#/1.}"
```

(since this array has two elements, indexed as 0 and 1)
and this expands to

```
$ ls "1.foo" "1.bar"
```

**Quoting**

The quotes are important if the “extensions” require quotes —
i.e., if they (might possibly, ever) contain spaces
or pathname expansion (glob/wildcard) characters. 
For example, if

```
$ extensions=("foo bar" "*r")
```

then

```
$ ls ${extensions[@]/#/1.}
```

(without quotes) would expand to

```
$ ls 1.foo bar 1.*r
```

(in which `1.foo` and `bar` are separate arguments),
and this, in turn, expands to

```
$ ls 1.foo bar 1.anteater 1.bar 1.bear 1.cougar 1.deer 1.grasshopper …
```

(because `1.*r` is an unquoted wildcard). 
For more discussion of the importance of quoting,
see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable
in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216).

**You can also match the end of a string** by using `%` in the *pattern*:

```
$ fnames=(cat dog)
$ ls "${fnames[@]/%/.c}"
```

expands to

```
$ ls "cat.c" "dog.c"
```

But beware: `%` ***doesn’t*** work the same as `$` in regular expressions. 
You have to put it at the *beginning* of the *pattern*
to constrain the match to occur at the end of the parameter value. 
For example, if you have

```
$ fnames=(cat.c dog.c)
```

and you want to get `cat.o` and `dog.o`,
***don’t do*** `"${fnames[@]/.c%/.o}"` — it won’t work. 
Do

```
$ ls "${fnames[@]/%.c/.o}"
```

But don’t do `"${fnames[@]/.c/.o}"` (leaving out the `%` altogether)
either — if one of the “fnames” is `dog.catcher.c`,
it will be converted to `dog.oatcher.c`
(since the *first* `.c` gets replaced with `.o`).

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to add a prefix and a suffix, as you would be able to with

```
$ ls 1.{foo,bar}.c
```

See the bash documentation for more information on variables, arrays,
and the transformations you can apply to them.