# bash combining wildcard expansion with brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I'm trying to expand a string involving a wildcard and a collection of extensions specified within braces.   Nothing seems to work as the example below illustrates.  the variable `firstList` expands fine, but neither `secondList`, `thirdList` or `fourthList` expands properly.   I've also tried various versions of `eval` but none work either.     Any help would be appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.ext1
touch b.ext1
firstList='*.ext1'
ls  $firstList
touch a.ext2
touch b.ext2
secondList='*.{ext1,ext2}'
ls $secondList 
ls '$secondList'
ls "$secondList"
thirdList=*.{ext1,ext2}
ls $thirdList  
ls '$thirdList'
ls "$thirdList"
fourthList="*.{ext1,ext2}"
ls $fourthList
ls '$fourthList'
ls "$fourthList"
```

Comment: fwiw `eval ls $secondList` works fine here... what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: You need to check the [order of bash expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) -- brace expansion occurs *before* paramater expansions. To get the effect you're hoping for, you need to `eval` to get a 2nd round of expansions.

Comment: Dupe of this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117144/28489

Comment: @glennjackman There is a solution without eval. Look at the [second solution at the end of my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284578/79743).

Answer (score 15):

The **shell** expands `*` only if un-quoted, any quoting stops expansion by the shell.

Also, a brace expansion needs to be unquoted to be expanded by the shell.

This work (lets use echo to see what the shell does):

```
$ echo *.{ext1,ext2}
a.ext1 b.ext1 a.ext2 b.ext2
```

Even if there are files with some other names:

```
$ touch {a,b}.{ext1,ext2} {c,d}.{ext3,ext4} none
ls
a.ext1  a.ext2  b.ext1  b.ext2  c.ext3  c.ext4  d.ext3  d.ext4  none

$ echo *.{ext1,ext2}
a.ext1 b.ext1 a.ext2 b.ext2
```

#### Why that works?

It is important that we understand why that works. It is because of the order of expansion. First the "Brace expansion" and later (the last one) "Pathname Expansion" (a.k.a glob-expansion).

```
Brace --> Parameter (variable) --> Pathname
```

We can turn off "Pathname expansion" for a moment:

```
$ set -f
$ echo *.{ext1,ext2}
*.ext1 *.ext2
```

The "Pathname Expansion" receives two arguments: `*.ext1` and `*.ext2`.

```
$ set +f
$ echo *.{ext1,ext2}
a.ext1 b.ext1 a.ext2 b.ext2
```

The problem is that we can not use a variable for the brace expansion.
It has been explained many times before for [using a variable inside a "Brace Expansion"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7738/79743)

To expand a "Brace Expansion" that is the result of a "Variable Expansion", you need to re-submit the command line to the shell with `eval`.

```
$ list={ext1,ext2}
$ eval echo '*.'"$list"
```

> Brace --> **Variable** --> Glob || --> **Brace** --> Variable --> **Glob**
>   ........ quoted here -->^^^^^^ || eval ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Values of the file names bring no execution problem for eval:

```
$ touch 'a;date;.ext1'
eval echo '*.'"$list"
a;date;.ext1 a.ext1 b.ext1 a.ext2 b.ext2
```

But the value of `$list` could be unsafe. However, the value of `$list` is set by the script writer. The script writer is in control of `eval`: Just not use externally set values for `$list`. Try This:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch {a,b,c}.ext{1,2}
list=ext{1,2}
eval ls -l -- '*.'"$list"
```

---

## A better alternative.

An alternative (without eval) is to [use Bash "Extended Patterns"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
list='@(ext1|ext2)'
ls -- *.$list
```

Note: Please be aware that both solutions (eval and patterns) (as written) are safe for filenames with spaces or new lines. But will fail for a `$list` with spaces, because `$list` is unquoted or the eval removes the quotes.

Comment: Yes, extended globbing

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
secondList='*.{ext1,ext2}'
ls $secondList
```

The problem is that *brace expansion* is done **before** *variable expansion*.  That means that, in the above, brace expansion is never performed.

This is because, when bash first sees the command line, there are no braces.  After `secondList` is expanded, it is too late.

The following will work:

```
$ s='*'
$ ls $s.{ext1,ext2}
a.ext1  a.ext2  b.ext1  b.ext2
```

Here, the command line has braces so that *brace expansion* can performed as the first step.  After that, the value of `$s` is substituted in (*variable expansion*), and lastly *pathname expansion* is performed.

#### Documentation

`man bash` explains the order of expansion:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion,
>   parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command
>   substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and
>   pathname expansion.