# Expanding item={one,two,three} with a wildcard

Tags: bash, wildcards

If I use `bash`'s brace expansion I get a list

```
echo item={one,two,three}
item=one item=two item=three
```

Assuming I am in a directory with files/folders that would match a wildcard, is there any way to have an expansion that matches these files/folders?

```
ls
blue  green  red

echo item=*      # Obviously not
item=*

echo item={*}    # Maybe? ...but no
item={*}
```

In my example I would like the expansion to be `item=blue item=green item=red`

The best I've got so is code like this

```
items=()
for dirent in *; do items+=("item=$dirent"); done
echo "${items[@]}"

item=blue item=green item=red
```

Comment: Do you want this as an array or as a string? Are you looking for something like `printf 'item=%s ' *`?

Comment: I see no issue with your loop. Is the intention to get a particular _output_ or to modify the contents of the array?

Comment: It's actually going to be an arguments array for interpolation into a command line (`rsync --exclude...`)

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284578/377345) contains a workaround using `eval` (yes, I know, "evil eval") - but in light of the answers posted here, it is probably a lot less helpful than I originally thought ...

Comment: @AdminBee oh I see, yes. I don't think I can use that here because my files won't necessarily have taggable extensions (or indeed any fixed part of the file name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store the current directory’s files in an array as follows:

```
items=(*)
```

Then parameter expansion can be used to add the prefix:

```
printf "%s\n" "${items[@]/#/item=}"
```

You can use this to update the array:

```
items=("${items[@]/#/item=}")
```

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
items=(*)
print -rC1 item=$^items
```

Or:

```
(){ print -rC1 item=$^@; } *
```

Or:

```
(){ print -rC1 ${@/#/item=}; } *
```

Or:

```
print -rC1 ./*(:s:./:item=)
```

Or:

```
set -o histsubstpattern
print -rC1 *(:s/#/item=)
```

Or:

```
print -rC1 *(e['REPLY=item=$REPLY'])
```

Or:

```
printf '%s%s\n' *(P[item=])
```

Or:

```
items=()
printf -v items 'item=%s' *
print -rC1 -- $items
```

etc.

For all of those add the `N` glob qualifier to get no output (or an empty line with the `printf` one) instead of an error if there's no matching file (here with `*`, that would be if the current directory is not readable or contains only hidden files).

Of course, if it's just about printing them, then you can just do (in any shell):

```
printf 'item=%s\n' *
```

Comment: I really ought to learn `zsh` one day