# Bash script - variables in curly braces

Tags: bash, for, brace-expansion

The following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

startNumber=$(( 1 ))
endNumber=$(( $startNumber + 3 ))

#for number in {$startNumber..$endNumber}
for number in {1..4}
do
        echo $number
done

exit 0
```

gives the desired output

```
1
2
3
4
```

However, when I switch the uncommented and commented for loop, the output is

```
{1..4}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Can I use variables inside {} expansion without `eval`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/can-i-use-variables-inside-expansion-without-eval)

Comment: Right, I edited it. Thanks, I'll have a look at it. So my first impression is that I can't do this elegantly and should do the for loop as @jesse_b suggested?

Comment: @Andrej: What is wrong with the c style for loop?  It's clean (would be a lot cleaner if you didn't use camel case variable names), and arguably more efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables won't expand inside [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).  You could do:

```
for ((number=startNumber; number<=endNumber; number++)); do
    echo "$number"
done
```

Also, there is no reason to use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) for `startNumber` you should simply do:
 `startNumber=1`.

Additionally, you don't need to use `$` to expand variables inside arithmetic expansion, so `endNumber` could be:
`endNumber=$((startNumber+3))`

Answer (score 8):

As explained elsewhere the expansion won't work.  Alternative way to get your sequence of numbers:

```
for number in $(seq $startNumber $endNumber)
do
  echo $number
done
```