# Why am I getting unexpected output while trying to loop for the number of times entered by the user?

Tags: bash, shell, for

I am writing this bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i N
read N
for i in {1..$N}
do
  echo "Number: $i"
done
```

(I believe `declare -i N` makes the `N` an integer)

However on running this, I get the following output:

```
>vim new.sh
>chmod +x passgen.sh
>./passgen.sh
15
Number: {1..15}
```

Here I want to take the limit from user, and then run the loop.

Comment: See [Bash script - variables in curly braces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619459/bash-script-variables-in-curly-braces) and the linked answers therein

Comment: Yes this answers my question @AdminBee
According to these and the answers, bash doesn't originally support loops with variable unless used with `seq` or a different style of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion,
> parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command
> substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and
> pathname expansion.

As you can see brace expansion is first, so apparently it is skipped in your problem. I'd use a different loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

While the problem with brace expansion has already been pointed out, I'll just comment on:

> (I believe declare -i N makes the N an integer)

I'll answer, yes, it does, and it's a problem as it makes it an command injection vulnerability. With that integer attribute set, whenever the variable is assigned a value, that value is interpreted as an arithmetic expression.

If the user enters `a[$(reboot)]` at that `read` prompt, that will cause a reboot attempt for instance.

That's a general problem with `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh` whenever arithmetic expressions are evaluated. Even using the `for (( i = 1; i <= N; i++ ))` ksh93-style form (with or without `declare -i N`) would be a problem as the contents of `N` is still evaluated in that arithmetic context.

`for i in {1..$N}` would be fine (without `declare -i N`) in ksh, zsh or `yash -o braceexpand` (would loop on gibberish but not introduce a command injection vulnerability), or you could use standard `sh` syntax provided your `sh` implementation is not based on `ksh`.

```
#! /bin/sh -
IFS= read -r N
i=1; while [ "$i" -lt "$N" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "Number: $n"
done
```

`ksh`'s `[` still treats operand of `-lt` as arithmetic expressions, so would still introduce command injection vulnerabilities. Do not use `[[ $i -lt $N ]]` or `(( i < N ))` in `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh` which also have the problem.

Or you could use `awk` / `perl` or any proper programming language to do the loop, or you could first sanitise the input.